# When to use strncpy or memmove?

Tags: c, string

(gcc 4.4.4 c89)

I have always used `strncpy` to copy strings. I have never really used `memmove` or `memcpy` very much. However, I am just wondering when would you decide whether to use `strncpy`, `memmove`, or `memcpy`?

The code I am writing is for a client/server application. In the documentation they use `bcopy`. However, could I do the same with the others?

```
bcopy((char*)server->h_addr,
      (char*)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
      server->h_length);
```

Many thanks,

Comment: `bcopy` is not a standard function, which immediately makes it inferior to the standard ones.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`strncpy()` is used to copy data from a source to a dest of a set size, copying (padding) `0x00`s if a `0x00` byte is found in the source array (string) before the end of the buffer.  As opposed to `strcpy` which will blissfully copy forever until a `0` byte is found - even if said byte is well beyond your buffer.

`memcpy()` is used to copy from source to dest no matter what the source data contains. It also tends to be very hardware optimized and will often read system words (`int`s/`long`s) at a time to speed up copying when alignment allows.

`memmove()` is used to copy from an overlapping source and destination area (say moving an array's contents around within itself or something similiar - hence the move mnemonic). It uses strategies (such as possibly copying data starting at the back instead of the front) to protect against problems caused by overlapping regions. It also may be slightly less efficient as there usually isn't much hardware help copying data from back to front.

`bcopy()` and its relatives (`bzero`, and a few others) is a byte copy function I've seen now and then in embedded land. Usually, it copies data one byte at a time from source to destination to prevent misaligned memory address issues.

Good luck!

Comment: strncpy doesn't terminate the copy early. strncpy writes exactly the given number of bytes, either only copying the start of the string if it is too long, or adding zeros to the end of the copy to fill the buffer.

Comment: Then I learned something new today as well.  I thought it terminated early.  (browses net...)  Lookie there.  Changing my explanation above now :)

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I just stumbled across this.  `memmove()` is not correct in your answer.  If the source address is greater than the destination address, it must start from the front.  If the source address is smaller, it must start from the back.

Comment: Where did you find that info?  I am curious for myself :)

Answer (score 12):

You should never use `strncpy` (unless you are dealing with that rare specific situation it was introduced for). The function is not intended to be used with zero-terminated C-strings. The name given to that function is just a historical blunder, and happens to be the main source of the confusion for the people who attempt to use it. `strncpy` is a function introduced to support so-called "fixed width" strings, not zero-terminated strings. Using `strncpy` with zero-terminated strings is bad programming practice, even though you can whip it into some resemblance of "working" for that purpose.

A function for limited length "safe" string copying does not exist in C library, however some implementations provide it under the name `strlcpy`, which already became a de-facto standard name for this function. If your implementation does not provide `strlcpy`, implement it yourself.

Also, it is true that in many cases you can replace `str...` function with `mem...` functions, i.e. when you know the exact number of characters to copy.

Comment: Sure? IMHO `strncpy` has nothing to do with fixed width strings, the only problem is that `strncpy` does not zero terminate the target string, if the source string is larger than the given size (which is the source of confusion..).

Comment: @frunsi: Absolutely sure. The history of `strncpy` is well-known and well-documented. There's no room for any "IMHO" here. The function was created to fill 14-character long file name fields in one archaic version of Unix file system. That's the only role it was ever meaningfully used for and that's the only role it is good for.

Comment: It has two problems: 1) it doesn't zero terminate if the source is long, 2) it fills with zeros to the end of the buffer is the source is short. Both are obvious and immediate sighs of fixed width strings, of course.

Comment: When I use strncpy. I always do the following strncpy(dst_str, src_str, strlen(dst_str) + 1)). This way you could never have a buffer overrun, as you will never copy more than the dst_str can handle. However, the question was when would you decide when to use either of them? Is there some criteria that you would decide on?

Comment: @robUK: Sorry, but this is plain nonsense. What on Earth the length of the current dst string has to do with the number of characters I want to copy? In fact, in 99 cases out of 100 the dst buffer will be uninitialized, so applying `strlen` to it just make no sense whatsoever.

Comment: Again, using `strncpy` with zero-terminated strings is like using a hammer to drive in woodscrews. Just because you can do it, does not mean you should.

Comment: @Andrey, I should have written sizeof(dst_str) instead of strlen.

Comment: @robUK: It is not enough to "not have buffer overrun". In addition to "not having buffer overrun", we also want to obtain the correct result (a zero-terminated string in dst) and we also want to avoid wasting time doing unnecessary work. `strncpy` doesn't help us with it, in general case. Which is why we don't use `strncpy` for that purpose.

Comment: I went down this road a while back and discovered just how bad strncpy is (for how it seems to be used as a 'safer' strcpy).  I did not find any historical reason for why it is so bad, but you explanation makes a lot of sense, and I don't hate strncpy so much.  It is too bad that strncpy is in the std libs and strlcpy is so not (usually), especially considering I have NEVER seen it used as you have described its intended application.

Comment: It it worth pointing out that if you pre-check to see if you are going to be truncating the string (due to insufficient destination space), then you will also know the exact number of characters to copy (so you can use `memcpy` / `memmove`).  By the way, one modern use case that I have found for `strncpy` was filling out a fixed-size buffer from a supplied password string, that was to be processed to create an encryption key.  `strncpy` was perfect for this (but it is so unusual that I actually put a comment in clarifying that I *really* did want `strncpy`!).

Answer (score 6):

`strcpy` (and other str* methods) stop when they encounter a NULL (0) byte. `memcpy` and related functions to NOT stop when they encounter a NULL byte.

If you have binary data, you must use memcpy. In your example, you are copying binary data, not string data.

`strncpy` is a special case where it will stop copying at a NULL byte, but still continue to pad the output with NULLs up to the specified length.

Comment: +1, Fair enough, though one might argue that all data is binary data. ;)

Comment: strncpy doesn't stop filling the target buffer, though. strncpy writes exactly the given number of bytes, either only copying the start of the string if it is too long, or adding zeros to the end of the copy to fill the buffer.

Comment: `memcpy` is also often faster for `'\0'` terminated strings if you happen to already know the length of the string.

Comment: @YannRamin
I wrote the following example:


`#include <stdio.h>`
`#include <string.h>`

`int main ()` 
`{`
`char arr1[] = {'S', 'o', 'm', 'e', 0, 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 0};`
`char arr2[] = {'S', 'o', 'm', 'e', 0, 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 0};`
`char arr3[12], arr4[12];`
    
`strcpy(arr3, arr1);`
`memcpy(arr4, arr2, 12);`
    
`printf("arr3 + strcpy:\t%s\narr4 + memcpy:\t%s\n", arr3, arr4);`
    
`return(0);`
`}`

Output:
`arr3 + strcpy:  Some`
`arr4 + memcpy:  Some`

Comment: @YannRamin
It appears that `memcpy()` also reads until first occurance of null-terminating character is met. Do I get things wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need the buffer-filling behavior of `strncpy` but want the safety of not overflowing the buffer, consider `strlcpy`

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strlcpy):

`strlcpy` offers two features that are designed to help software developers avoid problems. The function takes the size of the destination as a parameter, avoiding buffer overflows if the size parameter is correct. If this size is greater than zero, a nul byte is always written to the destination, so the resulting string is always nul-terminated (even if the source string was truncated to fit).

Comment: The main problem with strlcpy is that it's not actually C :-) It's an extension. Having said that, I believe it *is* available on gcc which is what the OP stated.

Answer (score 4):

Use `strncpy()` only if you know there's enough space for the string - because it does not guarantee null termination, and is over-enthusiastic if the destination is way shorter than the source string (because it null pads the string to full length).  And if you know the length, you can use `memmove()`...

If you know the lengths of the strings, `memmove()` is a sensible choice - and nominally faster than `strncpy()` because it does not have to check for nulls as it goes; it just copies the relevant number of bytes.  (I pretend `memcpy()` doesn't exist as it can fail if the source and destination areas of memory overlap, whereas `memmove()` will get it right regardless.)

Think of `bcopy()` as an archaic variant of the `mem*()` functions.

Comment: There is actually a difference between memcpy(dst,src,size) and memmove(dst,src,size) because memmove "moves" the memory - means: dst and src may overlap whereas overlapping must be avoided when using memcpy.

Comment: I didn't mention `memcpy()` - I pretend it doesn't exist.

Comment: `memcpy()` is cheaper than `memmove()` in most cases, as you usually know that the source and destination buffers don't overlap.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a safe/fast way to copy, I've been happy with the following technique:

```
memcpy( dest, src, sizeof (dest));
dest[sizeof(dest) - 1] = '\0';       // ensure null termination
```

Less efficient, but also works to limit the bytes written and null-terminate the string:

```
snprintf( dest, sizeof (dest), "%s", src);
```

Also returns the number of bytes it would have written, so you can tell if truncation took place.

Comment: `memcpy( dest, src, sizeof (dest));` invokes undefined behavior if the string pointed to by `src` is shorter than the destination array, because reading beyond the null terminator may reach memory that is invalid to read.

Answer (score 2):

A quick answer to an old question:

##### `strncpy`: don't use this function for any purpose whatsoever.

If you want to copy a string with truncation, either use `snprintf` or a this function:

```
// returns the length of the string if no truncation.
// otherwise truncate the string and return the destination size.
// destination is always null terminated if size > 0
size_t pstrcpy(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src) {
    size_t len = strnlen(src, size);
    if (len < size) {
        size = len + 1;
    }
    if (size > 0) {
        memmove(dest, src, size - 1);
        dest[size - 1] = '\0';
    }
    return len;
}
```

You can test for truncation this way:

```
void do_something(const char *str) {
    char dest[100];
    if (pstrcpy(dest, sizeof dest, src) >= sizeof(dest)) {
        printf("string too long was truncated\n");
    }
    // here dest is always properly null terminated
    [...]
}
```

##### `bcopy`: don't use this function either, use `memmove` or `memcpy`.

`bcopy` is an ancient BSD specific function to copy blocks of bytes. Use the standard functions `memmove` or `memcpy` for this purpose. They have always been part or the C Standard and even pre-date ANSI-C.

##### `memcpy` or `memmove`: prefer `memmove`.

Unless you are absolutely certain there is no overlap between the source and destination areas to copy, use `memmove`.

`memcpy` with a constant size usually compiles to very efficient inline code.  Leave that to those hairy geeks who like to waste hours trying to save nanoseconds.

Note that in C there is no need to cast the source or destination pointers as `(char *)` as posted in the question.

Also note that it is **very easy** to miscalculate the number of bytes to copy with `memmove`, `memcpy` or compare with `memcmp`: passing the number of elements instead of the byte size is a common mistake that no compiler can detect.  Here is a set of macros to avoid this pitfall when copying and comparing typed arrays:

```
/* Use these macros to avoid stupid size mistakes:
 * n it a number of items
 * p1 and p2 should have the same type different from void *
 * the macro checks that the types pointed to by p1 and p2 have the same size
 */
#define blockcmp(p1, p2, n)   memcmp(p1, p2, (n) * sizeof *(p1) / (sizeof *(p1) == sizeof *(p2)))
#define blockcpy(p1, p2, n)   memcpy(p1, p2, (n) * sizeof *(p1) / (sizeof *(p1) == sizeof *(p2)))
#define blockmove(p1, p2, n)  memmove(p1, p2, (n) * sizeof *(p1) / (sizeof *(p1) == sizeof *(p2)))
```

Passing pointers to different types may produce a division by zero that will be reported by the compiler.  Stricter type checking is difficult to achieve with portable code.