# Why is there garbage in strcpy from source to destination for 15+ chars?

Tags: c

I have this code -

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char *letter_data = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  char a[16];
  strncpy(a, letter_data, sizeof(a)+1);
  printf("The first sixteen letters are: %s\n", a);
  return 0;
}
```

When i compile this here - http://www.compileonline.com/compile_c_online.php

For a[4], a[5], a[6], a[10] etc, I just get the alphabets, which I expect. However, for any numbers other than these, for example a[7], a[8], a[16] etc, I get weird garbage after the string. I don't get where this garbage is coming from. Is this a C thing or the online compiler?

I would expect this garbage to be the null character at the end of each string, but the garbage is neither 1 char long, nor is constant. I was wondering what this is then.

Comment: I am aware of that. I am just wondering about the garbage after the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strncpy` does not zero-terminate the destination sequence if there's enough data in the source string to fill the buffer. Since the destination is not zero-terminated, it is not a string. Trying to treat it as a string leads to undefined behavior. This is what you observe.

Moreover, the purpose of `strncpy` is to serve as a *conversion function* from zero-terminated string format to fixed-width string format. It is not intended and has never been intended to be used as limited-length ("safe") string copying function. The output of `strncpy` in general case *is not a string*. This is exactly the problem you ran into.

You can read more about fixed-width strings and the real purpose of `strncpy` here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2886982/187690

Don't attempt use `strncpy` for limited-length string copying. Check if your platform offers `strlcpy` or implement an `strlcpy` analog yourself.

Comment: Why does a[14] print The first sixteen letters are: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO
while a[16] print ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQsñ`ÿ

Comment: @Aditya Bist: It is called "undefined behavior" for a reason. It means that anything can happen. In your experiment with 14 you just got lucky and hit some accidental zero in the garbage data, which accidentally properly zero-terminated the destination sequence. Tomorrow, you might try the same experiment with 14 and suddenly discover that now it prints garbage.