# C: Create own version of strncpy

Tags: c, strncpy

I am working on creating my own version of `strncpy`. My code seems to accept the input fine, but the program terminates after the input is entered. `strncpy` also seems to pad the copied function with nulls if it's shorter than the first - what is the point of that and how do I implement that in my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 50
#define STOP "quit"

char *copywords(char *str1, char *str2, int n);

int main(void) {
    char words[SIZE];
    char newwords[SIZE];
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Type a word, and the # of chars to copy, or type 'quit' to quit: ");

    fgets(words, SIZE, stdin);
    scanf_s("%d", &num);

    if (words == STOP) {
        printf("Good bye!\n");
        return 0; 
    }

    copywords(words, newwords, num);

    printf("The word was");
    puts(words);

    printf("and the copied word is");
    puts(newwords);
}

char *copywords(char *str1, char *str2, int n) {
    int i; 

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        str2[i] = str1[i];
    }
    return str2;
}
```

Comment: review how arrays work and what == means.

Comment: "`strncpy` also seems to pad...". Read about the real purpose and intent of `strncpy`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2886982/187690. What you are trying to do in your code has no relation to `strncpy` at all. And it really shouldn't.

Comment: The line `if (words == STOP)` will not work as intended. Look up `strcmp`.

Comment: @Markovnikov: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: **DO NOT USE `strncpy()`**.

You can read why here: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

The semantics of `strncpy` are obscure, widely misunderstood and error prone.  The size argument is the size of the **destination** array, not some limit to the number of characters to copy from the source.  If the source string length is `size` or larger, the destination will **not** be null terminated and if it is shorter, the remainder of the destination will be **filled** with null bytes (`'\0'`).

The reasons for these choices are historical: `strncpy()` was used to copy filenames into a memory structure for an archaic file system where filenames were limited in length.

The lack of null termination is **so error prone** that this function should **never be used** in production code, because the programmer or the maintainer will all too easily misunderstand the code's actual behavior and create bugs by modifying it.

If you must re-implement it as an assignment, you must implement the **exact** semantics.  It you just want to have a handy string function that copies a string with truncation, choose a different name and probably a different argument order.

Here are examples of both:

```
char *strncpy_reimplemented(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n && src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        dest[i] = src[i];
    }
    while (i < n) {
        dest[i++] = '\0';
    }
    return dest;
}

char *pstrcpy(char *dest, size_t size, const char *src) {
    size_t i;
    if (size > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1 && src[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            dest[i] = src[i];
        }
        dest[i] = '\0';
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Your `copywords` function has problems:

- You do not null terminate the destination if the source string is longer than `size-1`
- You dereference the source string beyond its length if it is shorter than `size-1`
- You do not check if the value typed by the user is within the proper bounds for the source and the destination arrays.

You have further problems:

- `(words == STOP)` does not check whether the string read by `fgets()` is `quit`. You must first remove the trailing newline from the buffer and use `strcmp()` to compare strings:

  ```
  words[strcspn(words, "\n")] = '\0';
  if (!strcmp(words, "quit")) {
      printf("Good bye!\n");
      return 0; 
  }
  ```

Here is a corrected and simplified version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *copywords(char *dest, const char *source, size_t n);

int main(void) {
    char words[50];
    char newwords[50];
    int num;

    for (;;) {
        printf("Type a word, or type 'quit' to quit: ");
        if (scanf("%49s", words) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
            return 0; 
        }
        if (!strcmp(words, "quit")) {
            printf("Good bye!\n");
            return 0; 
        }
        printf("Type the # of chars to copy: ");
        if (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {
            printf("Invalid input!\n");
            return 0; 
        }
        copywords(newwords, words, num);
        printf("The word was %s\n", words);
        printf("and the copied word is %s\n", newwords);
    }
}

char *copywords(char *dest, const char *source, size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n && source[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        dest[i] = source[i];
    }
    dest[i] = '\0';
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: "Padded with zeroes" – gosh. I didn't know and so never got used to *relying* on that behavior, but [look! there it is!](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-167/gen.subproj/ppc.subproj/strncpy.c): `while (n > 0) { *s++ = '\0'; --n; }`. GNU C uses [`memset`](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/gnu/glibc/string/strncpy.c). And now I'll have to try to forget that they do so.

Comment: Thank you! The code works fine except until "dest[i] = '\0'. I am using microsoft visual studio and I get the error identifier "i" is not defined.

Comment: @RadLexus: it is a good idea to remember that if you have: `const char *src = "abc"; char dst[20480]; strncpy(dst, sizeof(dst), src);` then this is going to write 20480 bytes, even though 4 would be sufficient for most people most of the time.  Do that a few times and the cost of rezeroing those extra bytes becomes significant.  (And don't even think of using `strncat()` unless you can tell me what the length argument means without looking it up — hint: it is _not_ the size of the destination array.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: `strncat()` is not as bad as `strncpy()` since the `n` argument really is the maximum number of characters to copy from the source string, which is exactly the purpose of the OP.  Yet I usually do not condone using it because it looks too similar to `strncpy()` which I definitely never allow. I favor safer utility functions that take the size of the destination array and truncate the copy or concatenation operations  instead of overrunning the buffer or leaving it unterminated.

Comment: I think it is worse because the size is not the size of the target, unlike most other size-limited functions. If you know enough to use strncat safely, you know enough to use a faster function such as memmove instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: it is not the size of the target, which should be obvious from the the order of the arguments: `n` is passed after the source pointer, not the destination pointer. The inconsistency and downright broken semantics of `strncpy()` is just so misleading!  I am using `size_t pstrcpy(char *dest, size_t dest_size, const char *source);`. `size_t pstrcat(char *dest, size_t dest_size, const char *source);` and their limited counterparts with an extra argument for the maximum count.. Just like `snprintf()`, the return value can tell if truncation occurred: it would be `>= dest_size`.

Comment: I agree with the argument for `strncpy`, padding with a `'\0'`'s on a 1M string can be costly, but I'm a bit confused why `snprintf` is taking fire. Just as a gun doesn't kill, `snprintf` doesn't fail to *nul-terminate*, the programmer does. If the argument is limited to maintainability and future programmers being confused and not understanding its use -- well, that doesn't put much confidence in the intelligence of those in the future. I find `snprintf` quite well behaved, and not easily replaced when a detailed format string is required. All good discussion.

Comment: @chqrlie when I run the program it freezes up after a word is entered.

Comment: @Markovnikov: the program does not hang, it is waiting for the user to input the number of characters.  I modified the program to have 2 separate prompts and to repeat the process until an error or the user types `quit`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The program does not hang when I use Compile Online but I does hang when I use Microsoft Visual Studio - I receive this error: Exception thrown at 0x0FFB0BA0 (ucrtbased.dll) in lab1113problem7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00B80000.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you dont add terminating character at the end of your sting after copying

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    str2[i] = str1[i];
}
str2[i] = '\0';
```

Why are you returning str2 if you arent using it?

Also i think you need cant compare by == operator

Edit:

Full Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 50
#define STOP "quit"

void copywords(char *str1, char *str2, int n);


int main(void)
{
char words[SIZE];
char newwords[SIZE];
int num;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

printf("Type a word, and the # of chars to copy, or type “quit” to quit: ");
fgets(words, SIZE, stdin);
scanf("%d", &num);
copywords(words, newwords, num);
printf("The word was ");
puts(words);
printf("and the copied word is ");
puts(newwords);
return 0;

}

void copywords(char *str1, char *str2, int n)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    str2[i] = str1[i];
}
str2[i] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Alright mate! I did that and my output is still garbage.

Answer (score 0):

Eh.  I would NEVER recommend writing "clever" code in favor of "clear" code, but here's an example of abusing a for loop to implement `strncpy()`:

```
char *my_strncpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n) {
    char *d;
    size_t i;
    for (i=0, d=dst; i<n; i++, *d++ = (*src == '\0') ? '\0' : *src++) { }
    return dst; 
}
```

Compound expressions, ternary logic that exploits short-circuiting, "putting everything in the for loop rather than in the body", it's got it all.  Don't go there!