# What explains this behavior of C compiler w.r.t string initialization?

Tags: c, arrays, string, buffer-overflow

The following code doesn't generate a null terminator

```
/* Case 1 */
#include <stdio.h>
void main () {
    char wbuf[16] = "0123456789abcdef";
    printf("%s\n", wbuf);
}
```

See the relevant parts of the dis-assembly

```
0x4005b4 <main+23>:  movabs $0x3736353433323130,%rax
0x4005be <main+33>:  mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
0x4005c2 <main+37>:  movabs $0x6665646362613938,%rax
0x4005cc <main+47>:  mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
0x4005d0 <main+51>:  lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax --->prinft related
0x4005d4 <main+55>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
0x4005d7 <main+58>:  callq  0x400470 <puts@plt>
```

Whereas the following code generates one:

```
/* Case 2 */
#include <stdio.h>
void main () {
    char wbuf[17] = "0123456789abcdef";
    printf("%s\n", wbuf);
}
```

Again see the relevant parts of the dis-assembly

```
0x4005b4 <main+23>:  movabs $0x3736353433323130,%rax
0x4005be <main+33>:  mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
0x4005c2 <main+37>:  movabs $0x6665646362613938,%rax
0x4005cc <main+47>:  mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
0x4005d0 <main+51>:  movb   $0x0,-0x10(%rbp) >>>>>> Null terminator comes here
0x4005d4 <main+55>:  lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax  --->prinft related
0x4005d8 <main+59>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
0x4005db <main+62>:  callq  0x400470 <puts@plt>
```

I would assume a string intialization like `char wbuf[xxx] = "yyyy"`  to add a null terminator, like in the second case. However the following questions linger :

1. Why doesn't the compiler warn *"too long initialization"* in the first case rather
   than silently avoid the null terminator. One more character like `char wbuf[16] = "0123456789abcdef\0"` triggers *warning: initializer-string for array of chars is too long* .
2. Would this behavior change across compilers. I was using *gcc on
   ubuntu* and was compiling with *O0* option
3. Why doesn't it behave consistently in 1 and 2, for e.g it could have
   blindly written past 16 in case1 and added Null terminator ?

`

Comment: That's just how the language is specified.

Comment: I think it's because you pass it as string, and string has to be NULL terminated so it may be undefined behaviour but not sure. So in general I think both are wrong.

Comment: `void main()` is wrong; it should be `int main(void)`. `char wbuf[16] = "0123456789abcdef";` is valid, as kaylum's answer explains. `printf("%s\n", wbuf);` is legal but has undefined behavior, because `wbuf` does not contain a (null-terminated) string.\

Comment: The object to be initialized is a charcter array (size=16); the string constant used as an initializer is ... a string. What are you initializing? The object. What is its size? 16. You told the compiler it should have size=16.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.7.9 on Initialization (emphasis mine):

> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string
>   literal or UTF−8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. 
>   Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null
>   character **if there is room** or if the array is of unknown size)
>   initialize the elements of the array.

So the compiler is conforming exactly to spec.

Comment: Does the spec say anything about implicitly  adding Null terminators to all  string initialization ? If I had an explicit \0 like (_char wbuf[16] = "0123456789abcdef\0"_ ) then the compiler would have warned I guess.

Comment: you would think the compiler would warn. Seems like an odd design choice to have one length generate a valid c string and the other generate an invalid one, without muttering a word

Comment: @jithu83: All four mainstream x86 compilers *do* warn these days, by default without even needing `-Wall`  https://godbolt.org/z/WMK2SR shows GCC/clang/ICC/MSVC.  ICC for some reason errors even in C mode.  (This code is illegal in C++.)

Answer (score 3):

In C language `char` arrays with string literal initializers can be used to define both regular zero-terminated strings as well as so called *fixed-width strings* (see [difference fixed width strings and zero-terminated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886931/difference-fixed-width-strings-and-zero-terminated-strings)). The idea of fixed-width strings is largely forgotten, but it had its role at the early ages of C language and Unix OS.

Fixed-width string conventions allow an array of, say, 8 `char`s to contain a fixed-width string of length 8 (without a zero terminator)

```
char fws_hello[8] = "Hello!!!";
/* `fws_hello` is a valid fixed-width string for width 8 */
```

It is most likely that the permission to have that terminating zero to "fall off the end of the array" is there in the language to support such strings.

Another language feature - all-or-nothing approach to initialization - can also be seen as serving the needs of fixed-width strings

```
char fws_hi[8] = "Hi";
/* `fws_hi` is padded with zeros all the way to the very end of 
    the array, which makes it a valid fixed-width string for width 8 */
```

I'd guess that C++ no longer saw the need for such string format, which is what allowed it to tighten its initialization rules and prevent the terminating zero from getting lost.

Comment: Interesting to note that C++ prevents case1 (null termination from getting lost)