# strcpy vs. memcpy

Tags: c, memcpy, strcpy

What is the difference between `memcpy()` and `strcpy()`? I tried to find it with the help of a program but both are giving the same output.

```
int main()
{
    char s[5] = { 's', 'a', '\0', 'c', 'h' };
    char p[5];
    char t[5];
    strcpy(p, s);
    memcpy(t, s, 5);
    printf("sachin p is [%s], t is [%s]", p, t);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
sachin p is [sa], t is [sa]
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884874/when-to-use-strncpy-or-memmove

Answer (score 142, accepted):

> what could be done to see this effect

Compile and run this code:

```
void dump5(char *str);

int main()
{
    char s[5]={'s','a','\0','c','h'};

    char membuff[5]; 
    char strbuff[5];
    memset(membuff, 0, 5); // init both buffers to nulls
    memset(strbuff, 0, 5);

    strcpy(strbuff,s);
    memcpy(membuff,s,5);

    dump5(membuff); // show what happened
    dump5(strbuff);

    return 0;
}

void dump5(char *str)
{
    char *p = str;
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
    {
        printf("%2.2x ", *p);
        ++p;
    }

    printf("\t");

    p = str;
    for (int n = 0; n < 5; ++n)
    {
        printf("%c", *p ? *p : ' ');
        ++p;
    }

    printf("\n", str);
}
```

It will produce this output:

```
73 61 00 63 68  sa ch
73 61 00 00 00  sa
```

You can see that the "ch" was copied by `memcpy()`, but not `strcpy()`.

Comment: Hello, I know that post is old, but I have two questions regarding it. First - `printf("%2.2x ", *p);` - why did You limit printf to 2.2 ? Besides I can see NO dot at all... Second - `printf("%c", *p ? *p : ' ');` - what does this test really check? If `*p` ?    Thanks in advance for Your answer!

Comment: In a printf statement, "x" means "base 16". "2.2" means: two and only two digits. The `*p` test means: "if you hit a null, print a space."

Answer (score 115):

`strcpy` stops when it encounters a NUL (`'\0'`) character, `memcpy` does not. You do not see the effect here, as `%s` in printf also stops at NUL.

Comment: @Sachin: Initialize `p` and `t` to something (all blanks, for example), then after copying, compare `p[3]` to `t[3]`. The `strcpy` didn't go beyond `p[2]`, where it found the null character, but the `memcpy` as directed copied five characters.

Comment: Minor nit-pick: strcpy stops when it encounters the NUL character (one "L").  NULL (two "L"s) is a compile-time constant for a pointer guaranteed not to point to any valid object.

Comment: if dest and src overlap, strcpy will throw out a seg-fault?

Answer (score 13):

`strcpy` terminates when the source string's null terminator is found. `memcpy` requires a size parameter be passed. In the case you presented the `printf` statement is halting after the null terminator is found for both character arrays, however you will find `t[3]` and `t[4]` have copied data in them as well.

Answer (score 10):

`strcpy` copies character from source to destination one by one until it find NULL or '\0' character in the source.

```
while((*dst++) = (*src++));
```

where as `memcpy` copies data (not character) from source to destination of given size n, irrespective of data in source.

`memcpy` should be used if you know well that source contain other than character. for encrypted data or binary data, memcpy is ideal way to go.

`strcpy` is deprecated, so use `strncpy`.

Comment: I don't know where did you see [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) being deprecated.

Comment: @RohanBari It's a royal outrage if this is someone with only MSVC experience speaking about "_deprecated functions_" all over again for the billionth time

Comment: `strcpy()` is **not** _deprecated_, it's only _discouraged_ (because `strncpy()` is less vulnerable to buffer overruns). Not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 5):

The main difference is that `memcpy()` always copies the exact number of bytes you specify; `strcpy()`, on the other hand, will copy until it reads a NUL (aka 0) byte, and then stop after that.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the null character in your `s` string, the `printf` won't show anything beyond that. The difference between `p` and `t` will be in characters 4 and 5. `p` won't have any (they'll be garbage) and `t` will have the `'c'` and `'h'`.

Answer (score 3):

- Behavior difference: `strcpy` stops when it encounters a `NULL` or `'\0'`
- Performance difference: `memcpy` is usually more efficient than `strcpy`, which always scan the data it copies

Comment: Performance-wise, it should really depend on the compiler and the platform. I've tested on two different environments and got these results: On Linux ARMv7L, `memcpy` was 1.5x faster than `strcpy`. However, on Linux x86_64, using GCC 13.1.1 and Clang 16.0.5, `strncpy` and `strcpy` both was faster than `memcpy` by 10% (maybe because of a modern compiler implementation?). Your mileage may vary, so you should test it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your test-program is, that the `printf()` stops inserting the argument into `%s`, when it encounters a null-termination `\0`.
So in your output you probably have not noticed, that `memcpy()` copied the characters `c` and `h` as well.

I have seen in GNU `glibc-2.24`, that (for x86) `strcpy()` just calls `memcpy(dest, src, strlen(src) + 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s",...)` stops printing the data when null is encountered, so both the outputs are same.

The following code differentiates between `strcpy` and `memcpy`:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[5]={'s','a','\0','c','h'};
    char p[5];
    char t[5];
    int i;
    strcpy(p,s);
    memcpy(t,s,5);
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%c",p[i]);
        printf("\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%c",t[i]);

    return 0;
}
```