# C++: strcpy non-ascii characters problem is possible?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a specific case of a problem in my following code;

```
std::string id = "123456789123456789" // it can be different sized string too.
std::string my_id = "TEST_" + id;
char* temp_my_id = (char *) my_id.c_str();
strcpy(temp_my_id, my_id.c_str());
PRINT("my_id value : ", temp_my_id);
```

It is a legacy code in my project and I suspect the temp_my_id returns non-ascii character. Is this possible?

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem and what are you trying to do here? You’re copying the contents of a string to itself? Why and what’s the actual problem?

Comment: From the [docs for `strcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) _"The strings may not overlap"_

Comment: Also, you're casting away const-ness. With all these real problems, I don't think we need to consider hypothetical problems about "non-ASCII" characters.

Comment: In `strcpy(temp_my_id, my_id.c_str())` `temp_my_id` and `my_id.c_str()` point into the same memory buffer. This is an error as @Ackdari told already.

Comment: Actually there is not a problem. It is about a problem possibility. I wonder if I don't any modification in the code can it return non-ascii chars.

Answer (score 2):

```
char* temp_my_id = (char *) my_id.c_str();
strcpy(temp_my_id, my_id.c_str());
```

source and destination can not have the same memory location in `strcpy` because both arguments are marked as `restrict`:

Bold test is mine:

> `restrict` is a keyword **(in C, not in C++)** that can be used in pointer declarations. By
>   adding this type qualifier, a programmer hints to the compiler that
>   for the lifetime of the pointer, only the pointer itself or a value
>   directly derived from it (such as pointer + 1) will be used to access
>   the object to which it points.

you can try

```
char a[] = "123";
char *b = a;

strcpy(b, b);
```

returns:

```
warning: ‘strcpy’ source argument is the same as destination [-Wrestrict]
```

again in C, in C++ it is also broken because source and destination can not overlap.

Comment: Thats not really an answer to the op's question regarding "non-ascii" characters but... good point!

Answer (score 1):

strcpy does not really care about the encoding, it copies until it finds a NULL byte. So you just have to be careful that

- the source ends with a zero byte and contains none in the middle
- the source is not longer than the destination
- source and destination should not overlap

see [strcpy vs. memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898364/strcpy-vs-memcpy) and
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/