# Fast way to remove bytes from a buffer

Tags: c, optimization

Is there a faster way to do this:

```
    Vector3* points = malloc(maxBufferCount*sizeof(Vector3));
    //put content into the buffer and increment bufferCount        
    ...

    // remove one point at index `removeIndex`
    bufferCount--;
    for (int j=removeIndex; j<bufferCount; j++) {
        points[j] = points[j+1];
    }
```

I'm asking because I have a huge buffer from which I remove elements quite often.

Comment: I though that uses pretty much the same technique. And the benchmarking I did seems to support that theory.

Comment: memmove would be always optimized according to underlying architecture. in worst case would be like yours. best case it will rock.

Comment: if order doesn't matter, swap the item to be remove to the end and decrement the size of the array

Comment: Can you use a linked list?

Comment: Do you actually need to remove the elements?  I'm guessing here, but it looks like you have a list of points for a mesh or somesuch.  It might be quicker to leave unused points in the point list and perhaps periodically produce a clean list (rather like a garbage collector).

Comment: @arx As OP mentioned, this is not for improving production code. He's looking for a solution merely for curiosity/academic purposes.

Comment: @Necrolis Order usually matters, but I think your idea is great if it doesn't, will keep in mind. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, sorry - removing elements from the middle of an array takes `O(n)` time. If you really want to modify the elements often (i. e. remove certain items and/or add others), use a linked list instead - that has constant-time removal and addition. In contrast, arrays have constant lookup time, while linked lists can be accessed (read) in linear time. So decide what you will do more frequently (reading or writing) and choose the appropriate data structure based upon that decision.

Note, however, that I (kindly) assumed you are not trying to commit the crime of premature optimization. If you haven't benchmarked that this is **the** bottleneck, then probably just don't worry about it.

Comment: @istepaniuk See the OP's comment: "I though that uses pretty much the same technique" - and it does indeed. One can't operate faster on an array. (Except if `memmove()` is called with only constants that can be optimized by the compiler, but here this does not seem to be the case.)

Comment: No, the curiosity was purely academic. No premature optimisation. Interesting that you mention linked list and the difference between read and write access. Something to think of. +1, I will choose your answer in a couple of minutes, to see if other have other things to say as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Meda You're welcome and ***thank you*** for not doing premature optimization!

Comment: @H2CO3 - It's true that `memmove` is still going to be O(N), but a lot of `memmove` implementations probably have hand-optimized assembly, so you might find you get a slightly better O(N).

Comment: @asveikau I don't see how hand-optimized assembly would improve it (apart from not having the prologue and epilogue "push/pop" instructions). One can write a `memmove()` function in C that moves 8 bytes at a time, and it will be translated to almost the same assembly that one would write by hand, since there's no possibility for black magic here.

Comment: some possible black magic: alignment, cache line size, prefetching, using vector instructions to copy memory... just look for an optimized memmove implementation

Comment: @auselen I've seen several of them :) Trust me, they were either compiler-generated (and thus automatically optimized) or handwritten, and there wasn't much difference.

Comment: @H2CO3 - It of course depends on what the compiler generates.  But yeah, I haven't benchmarked common `memmove` implementations specifically but in my experience I would not be surprised at all if some hand-rolled SSE thing beats whatever a typical compiler generates for `while (n--) *dst++ = *src++;`

Comment: Much difference? So there was a difference and I assume one was better. You can't just say "trust me" to people, this is not a social subject. Do you think engineers write code just like this http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-594.9.4/arm/string/NEON/bcopy.s and maintain it because it is fun?

Comment: @auselen Don't get mad. No, I don't think "engineers write code like this because it's fun". Of course its reasoning is that it's faster - but how much? I feel I will need to whip up a benchmark just in order you to sleep calm...

Comment: @H2CO3 sorry if I sound mad, that wasn't my intention.

Comment: @auselen No worries in this case, peace.

Comment: I still think you don't know what you are talking about. now try to get some nice sleep with that benchmarking ;)

Comment: @auselen I do know what I am talking about. We're discussing two conceptually different problems here - algorithmic (time) complexity versus actual running time.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you know it's a bottleneck you can probably let the compiler optimize for you, but you could try `memmove`.

The selected answer here is pretty comprehensive: [When to use strncpy or memmove?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884874/when-to-use-strncpy-or-memmove)

A description is here: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/memmove.3.html

Answer (score 2):

A few things to say. The memmove function will probably copy faster than you, often it is optimised by the writers of your particular complier to use special instructions which arent available in the C language without inline assembler. I believe these instructions are called SIMD instructions (Single Instruction Multiple Data)? Somebody correct me if I am wrong.

If you can save up items to be removed, then you can optimse by sorting the list of items you wish to remove and then, doing a single pass. It isnt hard but just takes some funny arithmetic.

Also you could just store each item in a linked list, removing an item is trivial, but you lose random acccess to your array.

Finally you can have an additional array of pointers, the same size of your array, each pointer pointing to an element. Then you can access the array through double indirection, you can sort the array by swapping pointers, and you can delete items by making their pointer NULL.

Hope this gives you some ideas. There usually is a way to optimise things, but then it becomes more application specific.